# Play Sounds on Startup, Logout, Lock, and Unlock

Tags: sound, login, startup, lock

The title says it all. I know of the common approach to add a command to `Startup Applications` but I am seeking some tool or extension that allows to set/disable/customize sounds for several common events such as login, logout, lock, unlock, etc.

Are there any options?